# unable to print multiple values in django

Tags: python, django

I have a code that tests if the different directories exist in the URL. Example - www.xyz.com/admin.php here admin.php is the directory or a different page
I am checking these pages or directories through opening a text file.

suppose the following is the file.txt

```
 index.php
members.html
 login.php
```

and this is the function in views.py

```
def pagecheck(st):
    url = st
    print("Avaiable links :")
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'file.txt')
    data_file = open(file_path,'r')
    while True:
        sub_link = data_file.readline()
        if not sub_link:
            break
        req_link = url + "/"+sub_link
        req = Request(req_link)
        try:
            response = urlopen(req)
        except HTTPError as e:
            continue
        except URLError as e:
            continue
        else:
            print (" "+req_link)
```

the code is working fine and prints all the webpages that are actually there in the console.
but when I try to return it at the last to print it in the Django page.

```
return req_link
print (" "+req_link)
```

it only shows the first page that makes the connection from the file.text. Suppose, all the webpages in the file.txt are actually there on a website. it prints all the in the console but returns a single webpage in the django app

I tried using a for loop but it didn't work

Comment: that `print()` after the `return` is never going to be executed

Comment: @AlanHoover i have tried the other way too, By keeping the print above and return below but still the same

Comment: you need to post the entire code that is giving the problem.  You posted working code, then a snippet that causes an issue without the context of where that snippet is causing you a problem.

Comment: @AlanHoover this is the full code, and its working the only problem is getting the full output printed in django, as it only shows the first connected webpage. but at the same time shows all the out put in the console.

Comment: You want to `return` an aggregate value.  `return` only runs once per function invocation.  In other words, you need to build your entire return value then `return` it.   Where are you putting that `return` that does not give what you want?

Comment: first create list or string with all values and later use `return all_values` after `while` loop.

Comment: @furas could you please give a code snippet ?  and thanks

Comment: well, it is basic knowledge. Before `while` create empty list `all_values = []`, inside `while` add items `all_values.append(req_link)`, and after `while` return list `return all_values` or string `return " ".join(all_values)`